# Accessibility and focus/jump to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility

I'd like to jump the focus to an anchor due to some accessibility need.

The reason of this is reading browsers. When I click the link "Focus to anchor", I want the browser starting to read the page from the anchor, but for that I need to focus it.

I also want the tab navigation starting from this anchor. I don't want to use tabindex, which is not really a good way to use it. I don't want to use the #hash in the URL as well, I don't need any auto-scroll in my page.

Unfortunately today my code below is not working. This is just an example to illustrate my need.

```
<div id="content">

  <p>Paragraph...</p>
  <p>Paragraph...</p>
  <a href="#">A link</a>
  <p>Paragraph...</p>
  <p>Paragraph...</p>

  <a name="myAnchor"></a>

  <p>Paragraph...</p>
  <p>Paragraph...</p>
  <a href="#">A link</a>
  <p>Paragraph...</p>
  <p>Paragraph...</p>

  <a href="javascript:;" id="focusToAnchor">Focus to anchor</a>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#focusToAnchor').click(function() { $('a[name="myAnchor"]').focus(); });
</script>
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: use :target, it does exactly what you request

Answer (score 1):

first you need to wrap the code in a `$(document).ready()` function next I would change the `name` attribute to an id and use a normal selector in the click handler

I would also use the hashbang as a href to maintain valid html, but prevent the default in the click handler

```
<a id="myAnchor"></a>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#focusToAnchor').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       $("#myAnchor").focus(); 
   });
});
```

**Update With Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/hxUpQ/11/ it doesn't seem to trigger the style, but the element is definately getting focused, as it is firing a focus event. I also tested to see if anything else was suddenly stealing the focus but no amount of my testing showed that was the case.

Comment: Just tested, this is not working. Do you have a jsfiddle example where it works?

Comment: The anchor element has no content, if you add some text content it works.

Comment: Confirmed, and that'll [provide link text that describes the purpose of this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H30.html)

Comment: o duh, of course :P I was looking at the other links in the fiddle and wondering why they weren't focusing. you can use any number of techniques for adding text but hiding it from sighted viewers, see: http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/